# D-Bus how to create and send a Dict?

Tags: c, ipc, dbus

I have a process which exposes a method to DBus with one of the arguments taking the following type signature `a{sv}`:

> Dict of {String, Variant}

[The libDBus documentation](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/api/html/group__DBusMessage.html#ga591f3aab5dd2c87e56e05423c2a671d9) for `dbus_message_append_args` fails to provide adequate reference for this. Some information appears in the [specification under container-types](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#container-types), specifically:

> A DICT_ENTRY works exactly like a struct, but rather than parentheses
>   it uses curly braces, and it has more restrictions. The restrictions
>   are: it occurs only as an array element type; it has exactly two
>   single complete types inside the curly braces; the first single
>   complete type (the "key") must be a basic type rather than a container
>   type. Implementations must not accept dict entries outside of arrays,
>   must not accept dict entries with zero, one, or more than two fields,
>   and must not accept dict entries with non-basic-typed keys. A dict
>   entry is always a key-value pair.

---

On attempting to append a dict I receive the following error message:

```
type dict_entry isn't supported yet in dbus_message_append_args_valist
```

Although I'm actually using `dbus_message_append_args`(I guess the error message is somewhat off).

There are two other alternatives to `dbus_message_append_args()` using either:

`dbus_message_iter_append_basic()` 
and
`dbus_message_iter_append_fixed_array()`

While I can create an empty Dict container with the following:

```
  const char * container_d_sig = "{sv}";
  DBusMessageIter iter, sub;
  dbus_message_iter_init_append(msg, &iter);
  dbus_message_iter_open_container(&iter, DBUS_TYPE_ARRAY, container_d_sig, &sub);
  dbus_message_iter_close_container(&iter, &sub);
```

Neither of the append methods appear to support adding a struct. Not sure what to try here...

Answer (score 6):

First, about D-Bus libraries: you talk about dbus-glib in several places but the functions you refer to are not part of dbus-glib but libdbus. If you are still trying to find the best way to use D-Bus, I suggest you forget both of these: libdbus is very low-level (it's documentation even starts with *"If you use this low-level API directly, you're signing up for some pain"*) and dbus-glib is deprecated. The best D-Bus API currently is GDBus which is part of [GLib GIO](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/): it's a far better designed API than either of the other two, well tested and supported.

Now, as for the actual question, documentation for `dbus_message_append_args()` does say it quite clearly:

> To append variable-length basic types, or any more complex value, you
>   have to use an iterator rather than this function.

In other words you should use `dbus_message_iter_open_container()` to prepare the iterator until it is pointing to somewhere where you can use `dbus_message_iter_append_basic()`. Note that in your example the dictionary is a container, the dictionary entry is a container and the variant is a container... In other words it gets pretty complex quite fast. If you really want to do it, look at e.g. [Connman](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/network/connman/connman.git/tree/gdbus) code for examples.

As I mentioned, the sane route is GDBus. There creating even much more complex signatures is pretty easy as you can use the GVariantBuilder API:

```
GVariantBuilder builder;
g_variant_builder_init (&builder, G_VARIANT_TYPE("a{sv}"));
g_variant_builder_add (&builder, "{sv}", "name1", my_variant);

/* Now use the builder results with g_dbus_connection_call()
   or g_dbus_proxy_call() */
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question. Are you saying that I can emulate adding a struct by making several `dbus_message_iter_append_basic()` calls? Also the reason for the low-level api is that I wanted this to work without the `GIO` dependency.

Comment: A dict entry is a container of type DBUS_TYPE_DICT_ENTRY. You open it with an iterator, append the contents, then close the container. With regards to GLib/GIO dependency: I cannot imagine a situation where avoiding Glib (when it provides an API you want) is a smart choice. The costs really are minimal yet it's very useful. Even the official D-Bus tutorial agrees with me: _"The recommended GLib API for D-Bus is GDBus."_

Comment: Could you add what you describe doing as code to your answer? I have failed to obtain the correct behaviour -- and the documentation does not provide examples.

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm not quite that invested... It's been years since I had to work with libdbus and I'm not going to go back now that better options exist. But take a look at Connman code I linked to: it's high quality and the method signatures they work with are complex enough to show a lot of different things.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question was asked awhile ago, but I had a very similar question recently, and after several hours of trial and error this is some code I came up with that works for me. Hopefully it helps someone else...

```
DBusMessage* testMessage()
{
    DBusMessage* mssg = dbus_message_new_signal("/fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0", "fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.Interface", "PropertiesChanged");

    DBusMessageIter iter, aIter;
    dbus_message_iter_init_append(mssg, &iter);
    if (!dbus_message_iter_open_container(&iter, 'a', "{sv}", &aIter))
        return nullptr;

    DBusMessageIter eIter;
    if (!dbus_message_iter_open_container(&aIter, 'e', NULL, &eIter)) {
        dbus_message_iter_abandon_container_if_open(&iter, &aIter);
        return nullptr;
    }

    const char* key = "test key";
    dbus_message_iter_append_basic(&eIter, 's', static_cast<void*>(&key));

    DBusMessageIter vIter;
    if (!dbus_message_iter_open_container(&eIter, 'v', "i", &vIter)) {
        dbus_message_iter_abandon_container_if_open(&aIter, &eIter);
        dbus_message_iter_abandon_container_if_open(&iter, &aIter);
        return nullptr;
    }

    dbus_int32_t val = 42;
    dbus_message_iter_append_basic(&vIter, 'i', static_cast<void*>(&val));

    dbus_message_iter_close_container(&eIter, &vIter);
    dbus_message_iter_close_container(&aIter, &eIter);
    dbus_message_iter_close_container(&iter, &aIter);

    return mssg;
}
```

This is C++ but should be pretty easy to adapt for C. The returned message has a signature of `a{sv}`. [The dbus docs](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/api/html/group__DBusMessage.html) are helpful-ish.